# Convert Dynamic List into JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am allowing my users to create different roles for themselves within my svelteKit application.
I have a text input with a button that adds that value to an array and shows in the div below.

[image]

I need to convert the array into a tiered JSON object so I can add it to my Postgres database `role_permissions` column as JSONB. I have tried `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` but I cannot get it to work.

Ideally formatted like this:

```
{
  "role_name"{
            "permission": true,
            "permission": true,
             ...
             }
  "role_name_2"{
            "permission": true,
            "permission": false,
             ...
             }
}
```

While my users can create roles with custom names the permissions available are all the same e.g.:

```
can_add_members: false,
can_delete_members: false,
can_edit_members: false,

can_create_roles: false,
can_delete_roles: false,
can_edit_roles: false,
can_assign_roles: false,

can_create_projects: false,
can_delete_projects: false,
can_edit_projects: false,
can_publish_projects: false,
can_view_projects: false,

can_assign_members_to_projects: false,
```

I can't figure out how to convert the object into a tiered JSON format. I know I need some sort of key outside of each object but I do not know how to do that.

This is how they appear in `console.log()`

```
{name: "Partner", can_add_members: false, can_delete_members: false, can_edit_members: false, can_create_roles: false, …}
{name: "Associate Partner", can_add_members: false, can_delete_members: false, can_edit_members: false, can_create_roles: false, …}
```

**The actual code:**

```js
    let newItem = '';
    
    // An array of the roles names that will also be saved to the database as is.
    let roleList = [];

    // The array that needs to be converted to JSON
    let roleListWithPermissions = [],
    
    function addToList() {
        roleList = [...roleList, {text: newItem,}];

        roleListWithPermissions = [...roleListWithPermissions, {
            "name": newItem,
            "can_add_members": false,
            "can_delete_members": false,
            "can_edit_members": false,

            "can_create_roles": false,
            "can_delete_roles": false,
            "can_edit_roles": false,
            "can_assign_roles": false,
            
            "can_create_projects": false,
            "can_delete_projects": false,
            "can_edit_projects": false,
            "can_publish_projects": false,
            "can_view_projects": false,

            "can_assign_members_to_projects": false
        }];
           
            newItem = '';
            console.log("ROLE LIST",roleList)
            console.log("PERMISSIONS LIST",roleListWithPermissions)
          
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is below, with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// the original Object as described/shown in the question:
let source = [{
      name: "Partner",
      can_add_members: false,
      can_delete_members: false,
      can_edit_members: false,
      can_create_roles: false,
    },
    {
      name: "Associate Partner",
      can_add_members: false,
      can_delete_members: false,
      can_edit_members: false,
      can_create_roles: false,
    }
  ],
  // here we use Array.prototype.map() to iterate over the Array of Objects:
  rolePermissions = source.map(
    // using destructuring assignment to retrieve the 'name'
    // property from the Array-element (the Object),
    // and assigning all remaining property-value pairs
    // to the 'rest' variable:
    ({
      name,
      ...rest
    }) => {
      // here we return a new Object, with the computed value of the
      // 'name' variable to set the property equal to the value of the
      // variable rather than the String of 'name':
      return {
        // and the property-value equal to the Object containing the 
        // rest of the key-value pairs:
        [name]: rest
      };
    }),
  // converting the Array of Objects into a JSON string:
  jsonRolePermissions = JSON.stringify(rolePermissions);
// logging that JSON string to the console:
console.log(jsonRolePermissions);
```

Reference:

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).
- [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: Thanks for this! The console.log shows it as JSON but whenever I try to add it to the Postgres database it's throwing an error: Array value must start with \"{\" or dimension information.  "malformed array literal: \"Test,Test\""

Comment: But the string you've got (`\"Test, Test\""`) doesn't appear in what you've shared, can you share something that more accurately shows what you're working with? It's entirely possible that you may have to ask another question, this time focused on the database insertion.

Answer (score 0):

you can transform roleListWithPermissions array to an object.

```
const finalResult =
  roleListWithPermissions.reduce((result, current) => {
    result[current.name]= {...current};
    delete result[current.name].name;
    return result;
   }, {})
```